# In Spring WebFlow, is it possible to continue the same flow after calling an external service?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflow

One of my subflows need extra information from a service provider page, I will redirect the user to that page to insert his information and then return back to the same place he was in the flow.

The `view-state` takes the user to an `externalRedirect`, and this page will then do a callback to a static URL I give them, so how I can continue the flow from there?

Answer (score 1):

You have all information you need to continue in your flowRequestContext.
 You can restore the last state (snapshot and execution)

Comment: An example would be useful. Maybe if I thought about it further, it would be apparent, but I'm wishing for specifics. You'd have the static URL be the flow/subflow URL and have the start state detect something to skip to current? Or maybe it's another approach I'm not envisioning? I'm intrigued.